# Change entries in large arrays at specific indices without for-loops

Tags: python

I try to set specific entries in a 2 dimensional list to the maximum of itself and another value.
In the following example img is representing an image read by cv2.imread. msk is a boolean-Array of the same dimension. I want to set all entries of img, where msk is True, to value if value > the specific entry. The following example always sets it to value even if value is smaller than the previous entry.

```
img[msk] = value
```

Something like

```
img[msk] = max(img[msk], value)
```

doesn't work.

Solving it with two for-Loops needs much more time as img represents a huge image (about 20000x10000 pxls)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work" -- if you get an error, what is it?  If it does the wrong thing, what does it do?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Are you using Numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's you problem, I will assume that `value` is a list, as otherwise it would not be 2 dimensional.

Now with Value as a list, you cannot compare `max(img(msk),value)` as both are lists, or if value is not, 1.  If that is the case what you may have meant is `max(img[msk])` or value is a list `max(img[msk]+value)` or finally if value is an int , `max(img[msk]+[value])`.

P.S I am assuming a lot of things, as you are a bit unclear. If I said something wrong, please correct me in the comments.

EDIT: Based on the OP's comment below, the problem is similar, you cannot do max of an array. Heres a solution, not sure if it is more expensive the iterating, but does not use it.

First do the first max

`img[msk] = value`

Then create a second max, which is basically only True if it has not already been masked, and if it is less than the value.

`msk2 = img<value`

Finally apply the second msk

`img[msk2] = value`

Heres an example

```
import numpy as np
img = np.array([[1,20],[3,4]])
msk = np.array([[True,False],[False,True]])
value = 7
img[msk]= value
# [[7,20],[3,7]]
msk2 = img  < value
img[msk2] = value
#[[7,20],[7,7]]
```

Comment: When a question is unclear it's a good idea to wait for the OP to clarify before submitting an answer. Use comments to request the needed info. Of course you can work on your answer while you're waiting.

Comment: Value is a integer. Here is a small example:
img = [[1,4],[1,9]]
msk = [[True,False],[True,True]]
value = 7
result should be: [[7,4],[7,9]]
So it set the entry at any index (where msk is True) to max(previous, value)

Comment: And `img[msk]`?

Comment: I use numpy.
img[msk] = value results in [[7,4][7,7]], it's a fast way to change any entry to a value depending on a boolean array of equal dimension

Comment: Here I updated my answer, It should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you, msk = img < value is exactly what I needed.
In your example the output should had been [[7,20],[3,7]] as the False in msk tells not to replace the "3". So the code I was searching for is:
    `msk = msk & (img < value)`
    `img[msk] = value`

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answer's your question. You are very welcome!